# jquery accordion not initializing with dynamic creation not sure why

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to initialize jquery accordion plugin dynamically from a rest ajax query. There is no console error just doesn't actually accordion the data.

I'm not quite sure what is wrong because im not that good with jquery. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>TheWayWardJourney</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="" />
        <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="css/ie/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.scrolly.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.scrollzer.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/skel.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/skel-layers.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/init.js"></script>      
        <noscript>

            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skel.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-wide.css" />
        </noscript>
        <script>
            function updateMessages() {
              var mess = $.getJSON( "http://10.0.0.6:3000/page_contact?read=neg.no&username=eq.zukeru&order=time.desc", function() {
                console.log( "success" );
              })
              .done(function( data ) {
                var html_insert = '<div id="accordion">'
                var stats = ''
                //console.log(data);
                console.log( "second success" );    
                  $.each( data, function( i, item ) {
                    html_insert = html_insert + '<h3>From: ' + item.name + '" </h3>' + '<div><p>Email: ' + item.email + '</p>' + 'Message: ' + item.message + '</p></div>';
                  });
                document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML = html_insert + '</div>';
              })
                setTimeout(function(){  updateMessages(); }, 10000);
            }
            updateMessages();

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
                    <section id="mess" class="four">
                        <div class="messaged">
                            <header>
                                <h2>Messages</h2>
                            </header>
                            <p id='messages'></p>
                        </div>
                    </section>
    </body>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
              $(function() {
                $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
              });
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Why have you included jQuery twice?  Once in the `<head>` and once between the `</body>` and `</html>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue: you are calling

```
$(function() {
  $("#accordion" ).accordion(); 
});
```

before your ajax request has completed, and therefore no accordi. `$("accordion").accordion();` needs to be called after

```
document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML = html_insert + '</div>';
// call accordion function here
$("#accordion" ).accordion();
```